# How do you set an optimal threshold for detection with an SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I have a face detection system with SVM as the classifier. The classifier outputs a confidence level, between 0 and 1 , along with the decision. As in any detection system, there are several false positives too. To eliminate some of them, we can use non-maxima suppression (Please see http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/teaching/recvis10/assignment4/). The confidence threshold for detection is set manually. For example any detection with confidence below 0.6 is a false positive. Is there a way to set this threshold automatically ?

For example using something in detection/ estimation theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for probability calibration you will find some research on a related  matter (recalibrating the outputs to return better scores).

If your problem is a binary classification problem, you can calculate the slope of the cost by assigning vales to true/false positive/negative options multiplied by the class ratio. You can then form a line with the given AUC curve that intersects at only one point to find a point that is in some sense optimal as a threshold for your problem.

Comment: This is a binary classfication problem. I am using SVM as a 'black box' that gives a binary decision and a confidence level (between 0 and 1).

Comment: Everything I stated still applies.

Comment: Also, SVMs don't have probabilities. A form of probability calibration (most likely Platt Scaling) was already applied for you. 

Everything I stated about AUC is still correct and doesn't change.

Comment: True, libsvm uses Platt's method (or a variation I think). Are you saying that even with these probabilities, I can still use AUC? Lets say I have positive samples S1, S2 and S3, and the corresponding probabilities output by libsvm are 0.58, 0.8 and 0.9. Using AUC (varying threshold and testing over a large set), I get, say 0.75 as the threshold. This means I will take only S2 and S3 as true positives. Is this the right approach?

Comment: You can use AUC for any binary task which you have score values, they need not be probabilities. There is plenty of info on how AUC works and how to compute it